# biblatex: Changing key MastersThesis to MPhilThesis

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Some universities have MPhil degree. I wonder how to put word MPhil thesis rather than MA thesis in biblatex bibliography. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

**Example.bib**

```
Example.bib contains the following entry


@MastersThesis{MPhil2015,
  Title                    = {Title},
  Author                   = {Author, A. B.},
  School                   = {Univ. XYX},
  Year                     = {2015}
}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\bibliography{Example}

\begin{document}

Test \cite{MPhil2015}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: @moewe: Thanks a lot for your useful comment. Would you mind to change your comment to answer so that I can accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want this change for a few `@MastersThesis` entries you can just use the `type` field to override the standard bibstring .

```
@MastersThesis{MPhil2015,
  Title    = {Title},
  Author   = {Author, A. B.},
  type     = {MPhil Thesis},
  School   = {Univ. XYX},
  Year     = {2015},
}
```

If you prefer "MPhil Thesis" to be the default, you can make it so via

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  mathesis = {MPhil Thesis}
}
```

Comment: Biblatex has also a generic `@thesis` type, which makes more sense semantically to me. The net result is the same anyway, one has to specify the `type` field.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Probably you are right. "MPhil" still means "Master of Philosophy", though, so technically one could say it is a master's thesis. But as you rightly point out, there is no difference in the output for the standard styles.